# Sort column based on property im passing to a Cell

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

```
        Header: "Votes",
        accessor: "Voter",
        filterable: false,
        Cell: row => <Voter id={row.index} vote={this.filterCount(row.index)} />,
        sortMethod: null //sort based on vote prop passed above ^
```

I want my table to be sorted based on the highest value of a property I'm passing to the Voter component in the cell. Except any value I pass to the `sortMethod` accesses the data from my JSON file, but i need to use data I've extracted extracted in the component. Is there a way? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: it could be clearer for readers if you can provide more information like which libary are you using to render table. And what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using react-table (which you've added as a tag), the sort method can be given a function that takes 2 values as arguments):

```
sortMethod: (a, b) => {
            a = (a === null || a === undefined || a === '') ? -Infinity : a;
            b = (b === null || b === undefined || b === '') ? -Infinity : b;

            a = parseInt(a);
            b = parseInt(b);
            if (a === b) {
              return 0;
            }
            return a > b ? 1 : -1;
          }
```

The sort method should work like normal sort methods javascript types use.  This is a very basic sort method, which simply goes by integer value and sorts a above b if it is higher, and handles any edge cases of undefined variables, pushing them to the bottom.

It is a little abstract, this is enough to tell it *how* to sort 2 items, which it will apply to all the rows. The values do not have to be named `A` and `B`, it's just simpler. A and B both represent 2 cell values. *IF* your cell value is an object, not an integer, then A and B are also objects, and you should use the value you want to compare. For example, if your cell values ARE objects, and you want to sort based on the voter_id, you would do:

```
return a.voter_id > b.voter_id ? 1 : -1;
```

instead of

```
return a > b ? 1 : -1;
```

Comment: thanks for the response. This is helpful. But I am still wonder how i can retrieve data that is external to the column. For example I would like to use row.index in my sort function. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: the sortMethod just extends the native Array.sort() function, so it can only use (value 1, value 2, desc) as args. If the cell is built from your custom component `Voter,` then it has access to that object in the sort. So if Voter component has an id, (which in your example code you have set to row.index), using `a.id` would be the row.index